# Java: Quando usar interrupt vs flags?

Tags: java, multithreading

Para indicar para uma thread que ela deve "interromper" seu trabalho o Java disponibiliza um mecanismo conhecido como [Interrupts](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/concurrency/interrupt.html):

```
public void run() {
    while(!Thread.interrupted()) {
        // Fazer algo
    }
}

// para interromper
minhaThread.interrupt();
```

Dito isso, não é incomum encontrar código que faz a mesma coisa "na unha" com uma flag `volatile`:

```
private volatile boolean running = true;

public void stop() {
    running = false;
}

public void run() {
    while(running) {
        // Fazer algo
    }
}

// para interromper
minhaThread.stop();
```

Quando devo usar cada uma dessas técnicas?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

O uso de uma flag `volatile`, como apresentado na questão, não traz benefício algum além de uma sensação por parte do desenvolvedor de ter em suas mãos o "controle" de execução. :)

## [Interrupções](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/concurrency/interrupt.html)

A API de Threads do Java implementou uma flag de uso genérico para gerenciar interrupção de threads "pausadas".

Se uma thread está pausada numa chamada a `Object#wait()`, `Thread#join` ou `Thread#sleep`, o método [`interrupt()`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/Thread.html#interrupt--) é capaz de "acordá-la". Na prática, é como se houvesse ocorrido um erro na chamada a um desses métodos e ele lançasse a exceção `InterruptedException`.

Determinadas operações de entrada e saída (I/O) também podem ser afetadas, por exemplo as que usam [`InterruptibleChannel`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/nio/channels/InterruptibleChannel.html).

A implementação da flag de interrupção é nativa, portanto a JVM pode utilizar mecanismos mais otimizados para comunicação entre as threads.

Portanto, se usada corretamente, a API provê mecanismos avançados para interromper a execução de uma thread mesmo quando há operações demoradas sendo executadas, como acesso a arquivos e rede.

## Interrupções e laços

Tal flag também é comumente usada para interromper *laços*, como no exemplo da pergunta.

O único perigo em se fazer isto é não controlar o estado da flag de interrupção devidamente.

Por exemplo, se você tratar a exceção de interrupçã:

```
public void run() {
    while(!Thread.interrupted()) {
        // Começa algo
        try {
            // Faz algo que pode lançar InterruptedException
        } catch (InterruptedException e) {
            log.error(e);
        }
        // Finaliza algo
    }
}
```

O código acima vai resultar num *laço* infinito porque capturar a exceção limpa a flag e a condição de saída do laço será sempre falsa!

Por causa disso, se houver necessidade de capturar tal exceção, em geral [recomenda-se](http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/library/j-jtp05236/) que se restaure a interrupção no `catch`, assim:

```
public void run() {
    while(!Thread.interrupted()) {
        // Começa algo
        try {
            // Faz algo que pode lançar InterruptedException
        } catch (InterruptedException e) {
            Thread.currentThread().interrupt();
            log.error(e);
        }
        // Finaliza algo
    }
}
```

Como o tratamento da exceção pode estar "escondido" dentro de outro método, alguns recomendam, por precaução, sempre chamar o `interrupt` dentro de um `catch` que capture tal exceção.

## Flag `volatile`

Controlar manualmente com uma flag possui algumas desvantagens, dentre as quais eu considero as piores:

- Necessário o compartilhamento de variáveis. As threads precisam se comunicar diretamente, aumentando o acoplamento.
- Incapacidade de interromper threads em espera.
- Desenvolvedores que não entendem o `volatile`. Alguns tentam imitar o uso e se esquecem do modificador, podendo levar a condições de corrida e comportamentos inesperados.

Por outro lado, há vantagens nesta abordagem:

- Se a flag não for simplesmente um `boolean`, isto é, se existe algum objeto mais complexo que é compartilhado. Por exemplo, no caso de threads consumindo uma fila, a "flag" pode ser a fila estar vazia.
- Se um número arbitrário de threads depende da mesma flag.
- Se não é desejado que não ocorra interrupção imediata da atual iteração da thread. Pode ser, por exemplo, que o objetivo seja apenas finalizar o laço, mas qualquer operação aguardando por `wait` ou `join` deve continuar até o final.
- O uso de uma flag num laço trivial como da questão é mais simples de entender, comparado com a API.

## API confusa

Infelizmente, a API para controle de interrupção do Java é um tanto confusa. Compare os métodos disponíveis:

- `Thread.interrupt()`: interrompe uma thread. Deve ser chamado diretamente num objeto, que pode ser a thread atual (como no exemplo mais acima) ou alguma outra thread, caso você queira interrompê-la. Este método ativa a flag de interrupção.
- `Thread.isInterrupted`(): verifica se a flag de interrupção está ativa para uma dada thread. Também deve ser chamado num objeto, que pode ser a thread atual ou outra thread.
- `Thread.interrupted()`: retorna o estado da flag de interrupção e **limpa a flag**. Este é um método estático da classe, portanto é chamado sem um objeto e sempre faz referência à thread atual.

Os dois primeiros métodos fazem muito sentido, mas o último é um tanto estranho, pois uma vez que seja invocado ele efetivamente limpa a flag. isto leva a situações inusitadas como quando uma expressão booleana usada num `if` modifica o estado e o código a seguir "vê" outros valores.

## Considerações

Minha sugestão é utilizar a API por padrão, quando isto se aplicar ao problema. Se houver uma necessidade mais específica, uma solução manual é necessária e não há problemas com isto.

Não é errado usar uma flag, mas para um desenvolvedor maduro é importante aprender a usar a API do Java - ou qualquer linguagem que usa. Faz parte disso  evitar soluções *ad hoc* quando possível.

Comment: Perfeito como sempre @utluiz. Vou deixar um bounty ;).

Comment: `O código acima vai resultar num laço infinito porque capturar a exceção limpa a flag!

Por causa disso, se houver necessidade de capturar tal exceção, em geral recomenda-se que se restaure a interrupção no catch, assim:`

Tudo isso é verdade, mas o seu loop continua a ser infinito se nao tiver um `return` no `catch`

Comment: @BrunoCosta Bruno, não vai porque existe a condição no while. Quando a thread interrompe a si mesma, neste caso, ela restaura a flag de interrupção e vai retornar true no método interrupted.

Comment: @utluiz Oops, é verdade...

Comment: Tem também o `isInterrupted()` que não limpa o estado da flag. Eu nunca entendi o motivo de `interrupted()` ser estático... Enquanto isso, dentro de um `Runnable` você precisa chamar `currentThread().isInterrupted()` para acessar a variante que não limpa a flag. Para mim a opção que não limpa a flag deveria ser a *default*

Comment: utluiz, juro que não vou transformar sua resposta no debate interminável e desnecessário de sempre... Mas já transformando no debate interminável e desnecessário de sempre, o `volatile` seria desnecessário mesmo se `stop()` for invocado de outra `Thread`?

Comment: @AnthonyAccioly Esses métodos de interrupção são um caos. Depois vou incluir um tópico na resposta sobre isso. Sobre o volatile, não quis dizer que é desnecessário. Provavelmente me expressei mal em algum ponto. Eu quis dizer que a flag é desnecessária.

Answer (score 5):

*Threads* podem entrar em modo de espera e aguardar uma condição para continuarem. No caso do `wait()` essa condição é um `notify()` ou `notifyAll()`. No caso de um `sleep()` é simplesmente que o tempo de "sono" seja decorrido.

Use `interrupt()` quando quiser fazer a *thread* sair mais cedo desses modos de espera, o que fará ela lançar uma `InterruptedException`.

Por outro lado, use <strike>uma flag</strike> o mecanismo de `interrupt()` e cheque o status interrompido da *thread* quando esta estiver executando operações lógicas (ela não está em modo de espera) e você deseja que ela finalize uma dessas operações e não continue as próximas. Por exemplo, se ela estiver gravando uma lista de arquivos e você quiser que ela pare ao completar a gravação de um dos arquivos, sem continuar gravando os próximos.

Deve-se ter atenção com o método usado para verificar o status de interrompido, pois embora o `isInterrupted()` não limpe o status da flag, outros métodos como o `interrupted()` limpam.

Há um uso para o `volatile` em *multithreading*, mas eu confesso que meu conhecimento é incompleto e não sei por que ele está sendo usado neste caso. Acredito que não é necessário no cenário que eu descrevi.

Answer (score 3):

Entendo que são coisas um pouco diferente!

Para usar `interrupt` é necessário que dentro de seu método `run` lance uma `InterruptedException`, para que ao chamar o `interrupt` este lance a Exception.

Os casos que a `InterruptedException` deve ser implementada:

1. `java.lang.Object#wait()`
2. `java.lang.Object#wait(long)`
3. `java.lang.Object#wait(long, int)`
4. `java.lang.Thread#sleep(long)`

Um exemplo de como parar um método `run` através do `interrput` :

```
public void run() {
        int pt = 0;
        try {
            while(true){
                System.out.println("ActionInterrupt {"+pt+"}");
                Thread.sleep(123L);
                pt++;
            }
        } catch (InterruptedException e) {
        // VAI CAIR AQUI, QUANDO CHAMAR O INTERRUPT!
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
```

Já com a flag, não há necessidade! ela é mais simples e direta!

Não preciso da `Exception` para interromper a atividade!

**Conclusão**:

Se sua `Thread` não lançar uma `InterruptedException`, então deve se utilizar a flag.

[Segue um exemplo!](http://ideone.com/neC3p4)

Comment: Oi Thiago, mas além de lançar a `InterruptedException` caso a Thread esteja "esperando" em um desses métodos parece que também há outra forma de verificar a interrupção (como no meu exemplo). Uma chamada a `interrupt()` também modifica um estado que pode ser lido com `isInterrupted()` ou o método estático `interrupted()`. Me parece que a Exception é complementar ao estado de interrupção... Ou seja, `interrupt` aparentemente faz o mesmo que a flag e mais alguma coisa, correto?

Comment: Então, a forma de verificar a interrupção com a flag seria verificar seu estado:  `while(suaThread.running)`. Por isso ela deverá ser `volatile`, para  que seu valor seja disponibilizado para todas as Thread´s em tempo real. Se sua Thread não entrar em um dos 4 estados citados, o método `interrupted` sempre retornará `false`! Tecnicamente o `interrupt` vai terminar o `sleep`  antes do esperado, enquanto a flag vai respeitar o while. O @Piovezan, deu uma ótima explicação sobre isso!

Comment: Acho que para as duas formas funcionarem iguais, depende da implementação! Se você deixar o `try{ }cath` dentro de um `while`  o `isInterrupted` não irá atualizar! [Segue um exemplo](http://ideone.com/xvFo9Z)

Comment: Sim, esse é o meu ponto. A `InterruptedException` é uma *feature* extra para lidar com threads em `WAITING`, `TIMED_WAIT`, etc. Dito isso, segue um exemplo em que a thread é interrompida sem entrar em nenhum dos métodos citados (apenas verificando o método `interrupted()` que retorna `true` corretamente após a chamada para `interrupt()`): [Link para o exemplo](https://goo.gl/6WVjSx)

Comment: @AnthonyAccioly Entendo. De fato é como você falou, o mecanismo de interrupt dispensa o uso da flag. Atualizei minha resposta de acordo.

Answer (score 1):

Minha experiência

- Seu projeto é simples.
- Poucas threads
- Poucas rotinas

Então podemos considerar tal cenário como qualquer solução bem implementada serve.
Contexto, participei de um projeto onde o processamento paralelo era o principal requisito.

Qualquer uma dessas soluções adotadas ou proposta ai não atende.

- Primeiro item complexidade alta
- Grandes problemas de flags, tags e estados de objetos
- Depende muito de você programador fazer o código (controle do processamento paralelo).
- Segundo juntar a 1, 2, 3, frameworks diferentes, jsf, Quartz, JbossSeam e um servidor Weblogic por exemplo.
- Hibernate, transações e IOC.
- Pouca experiencia, falta de tempo, gente dando ponta pé pra todo o lado, todos perdidos.

Isso nunca vai funcionar.

**Solução**:

Use um controlador de pool de threads:

- ThreadPoolExecutor (exemplo)
- Domine transações
- Processamento paralelo (o que pode executar paralelamente)
- Blocos de código protegidos, sincronizados (não deve sincronizar e sim ter várias instancias, mas as vezes isso não é possível)
- Controle completo dos ciclos de transações
- Controle completo de IOC (se usar no projeto)
- Se possível use thread pool dos próprios framework, geralmente são bons.

Em si é essas a recomendações que sirva para algum gerente de projeto ou analista, até mesmo para programadores em geral.

Comment: Bem relevante para projetos reais, embora não responda diretamente ao que foi perguntado.